# 2 tables, receive Id from one table and add value to another table but with id

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

My web app is about an online pool, it has `Model.Question` and `Model.Answer`.

In question I have `Id`, `Text` (Value of the question), `List of Answers`, `StartDate`, `EndDate` and if it's `active`.

In the Answer model I have `Id`, `QuestionId`, `Text`(Value of the Answer), and `Votes` (don't want to use it right now)

I'm having issues when I retrieve value from Question (Id) so the `Answer.QuestionId` has it Id. Then I need to add my `Model.Answer.Text` to `Question.Answer`;

Here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult AddAnswer(int id)
{
        //return View();
        using (var poolDbContext = new PoolContext())
        {
            Answer answer = poolDbContext.Answers.Find(id);
            return View(answer);
        }
}

[HttpPost, ActionName("AddAnswer")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AddAnswerPost([Bind("Id, Answers")] Question question, Answer answer)
{
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (var poolDbContext = new PoolContext())
                {
                    answer.QuestionId = question.Id;
                    poolDbContext.Answers.Add(answer);
                    question.Answers.Add(answer);
                    repository.Add(question);
                    repository.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException /* ex */)
        {
            //Log the error (uncomment ex variable name and write a log.
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. " +
                "Try again, and if the problem persists " +
                "see your system administrator.");
        }

        return View(answer);
}
```

Comment: What kind of issues? You didn't quite explain what is the problem, so it's hard to help. Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: Im getting the Question.Id value on my Answer.Id

Comment: So, you just want to add a new answer to an existing question?

Comment: @jpgrassi yes I might be dumb or something, but I can not do this ahha

Comment: No question is dumb :). Will post here something so you could try it.

Comment: Oh, but i'm feeling dumb because in logic is easy to say how to do but then when I need to code it my brain just frezes ahha, but thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you could change your code (omitted the rest of controller for brevity) to something like this:

```
using (var poolDbContext = new PoolContext())
{
    // get the question from db, also including the answers
    var questionFromDb = poolDbContext.Questions
    .Include(q => q.Answers)
    .Single(q => q.Id == question.Id);

    // good idea to validate if the question exists..
    if (questionFromDb == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Question not found.");

    // if answer is a new answer and not an update, 
    // then just add it to the current answers.
    answer.QuestionId = questionFromDb.Id;
    questionFromDb.Answers.Add(answer);

    // dbContext is tracking changes, so you don't need to add to the dbSet.
    repository.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

But.. this assumes some things:

- The Id on `Answer` is an int with auto increment setup. If this is the case then it will work. If it's a `Guid` for example, then you need to create the Id first, so keep that in mind.
- You have a `repository` which I don't know what it is. But, since you are using the dbContext right there, I don't see the use for it, so totally ignored in my solution

And.. some other advice for you:

- Don't use your EF entities as types for your controller actions. Instead, create some ViewModels. EF entities can be complex, and most of the times your clients only work with parts of it. So it's considered a good practice to use another type for returning/posting to your actions. [Read more here](https://juristr.com/blog/2012/10/lessions-learned-dont-expose-ef-entities-to-the-client-directly/)
- In general, you could inject the `DbContext` in your controller. This way you don't have to instantiate it in your controller and it's lifetime is managed by the DI system ([if you configure it correctly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext))
- Also check global exception handling. There's bunch of resources on the web.. but basically what you would want is to avoid the try/catch in your controller with repetitive exception handling.

Hope it helps clarify things a bit.

Comment: I'm getting an error on the "'.Include'" ( line 5) , the  error messages is :

'PoolContext' does not contain a defeniion for 'Include' and no extencion method 'Include' accepting a first argument of type 'PoolContext' could be found ( are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference ?)

Comment: Ah sure, I forgot to add which `DbSet` you are querying from. `poolDbContext.Questions` (or whatever is the name of Questions dbSet)

You should maybe read some EF.. because this was a very easy mistake to fix. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/basic

Comment: Answer.Id still gets the value from Question.Id, why is that?
my Answer.Id is an auto increment I dont understand why this is happening

Comment: Really hard to help you without seeing your code.. maybe something else is changing this field.. Can you share how you configure your DbContext? Maybe post the code for Question and Answer class along the PoolContext.

Comment: Well, what was it then? Don't leave me curious now :)

Comment: Had to change my get and my view, because in my get I was recieving the wrong id, the in my view had to change some minor things, if you want I can add it as an answer here

Comment: Thanks anyway, you're response did helped me alot